# Maximizing or Minimizing in Trust Region Policy Optimization?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, optimization, deep-rl, trust-region-policy-optimization

I happened to discover that the [v1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05477v1) (19 Feb 2015) and the [v5](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05477) (20 Apr 2017) versions of TRPO papers have two different conclusions. The Equation (15) in v1 is $\min_\theta$ while the Equation (14) in v2 is $\max_\theta$. So, I'm a little bit confused about which one to choose.

BTW, I found that in the [High-Dimensional Continuous Control Using Generalized Advantage Estimation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02438), the Equation (31) uses $\min_\theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences you have observed between the two different versions of the TRPO paper are due to different formalizations of the problem and the objective.

In [the first version of the paper you linked](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05477v1), they start out in Section 2 by defining Markov Decision Processes (MDPs) as tuples that, among other things, have a **cost function** $c : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. They define $\eta(\pi)$ as the expected discounted **cost** of a policy $\pi$, and subsequently also define state-action value functions $Q_{\pi}(s_t, a_t)$, value functions $V_{\pi}(s_t)$, and advantage functions $A_{\pi}(s, a)$ in terms of **costs**. Ultimately, in Equation 15, they write the following:

\begin{aligned}
\underset{\theta}{\text{minimize }} & \mathbb{E}_{s \sim \rho_{\theta_{\text{old}}}, a \sim q} \left[ \frac{\pi_{\theta}(a \vert s)}{q(a \vert s)} Q_{\theta_{\text{old}}}(s, a) \right] \\ 
\text{subject to } & \mathbb{E}_{s \sim \rho_{\theta_{\text{old}}}} \left[ D_{KL}(\pi_{\theta_{\text{old}}}(\cdot \vert s) ~ \vert \vert ~ \pi_{\theta}(\cdot \vert s)) \right] \leq \delta
\end{aligned}

Now, there's a lot going on there, but we can **very informally** "simplify" it to only the parts that are relevant for this question, as follows:

$$\underset{\theta}{\text{minimize }} \mathbb{E} \left[ Q(s, a) \right]$$

When we look at just that, we see that we're pretty much trying to minimize $Q$-values, which are **costs**; that makes sense, typically **costs** are things we want to **minimize**.

---

In the [second version of the paper you linked](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05477), they have changed the Preliminaries in Section 2. Now they no longer have a cost function $c$ in their definition of an MDP; they have replaced it by a **reward function** $r : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then they move on to define $\eta(\pi)$ as the **expected discounted reward** (rather than expected discounted cost), and also define $Q$, $V$ and $A$ in terms of **rewards** rather than costs. This now all matches the standard, common terminology in Reinforcement Learning.

Ultimately, Equation 14 looks identical to what we saw above, it's again about an expectation of $Q$-values. But, now $Q$-values are **rewards** rather than **costs**. Rewards are generally things we want to **maximize**, rather than **minimize**, so that's why the objective swapped around.